# onclick() doesn't respond in a <div> nested in a <marquee>

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, marquee

Before anyone goes off, this is *only* a 'quick and dirty'  proof-of-concept bit of code we're doing -- although it's hated, the marquee tag continues to be supported on every browser we have checked so it's a good facsimile for the POC code-up and easy to code up (and we're not using jquery).

But onclick() fails to work -- here's the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function dohello()
 {
     alert("HELLO !!");
 }

 </script>    
 </head>
 <body>

 <marquee behavior="scroll" scrolldelay="135"><div onclick="dohello()">THEE MARQUEE!!      
 </div>
 </marquee>    
 </body>
 </html>
```

The text "THEE MARQUEE!!" successfully moves across the page, marquee-style, but the dohello() is not getting called on a mouse click.

I used f12 and the console reports no errors at all.

What can I do for a mouse click handler on the div inside the marquee tag?

Comment: Hm, seems to work fine for me. Tested 2 methods of calling a function on the event [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89QuM/)

Comment: the fiddle isn't working, I'm using firefox  v28...what's your browser?

Comment: @CarlMarkham your fiddle is working in chrome, but not in firefox

Comment: Good catch. Not sure why it wouldnt work in FF. Even IE seems to manage it.

Comment: just noticed that using an input type = button, the onclick handler works fine.  but not in a div.

Comment: Seems marquee is deprecated by firefox

Comment: Get rid of `marquee` it's `Microsoft`'s proprietary tag, won't work in all browsers.

Comment: You can close your `<marquee />` tag or `</marquee>` not sure if that helps. It may be the browser you are using. Firefox tends to complain if things aren't closed properly, unlike chrome.

Comment: thanks, forgot to copy that from my actual code, I've added it now, the closing tags were in my original code.

Comment: Check this out: Not supported in all browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee Maybe see if there is a CSS property that allows you to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could try by reverse finding it based on mouse position with

```
var element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint

What are you coding for IE 6?? Just use CSS transitions or animations. they are easy and support events way better than marquees apparently.

**EDIT**
JSFIddle of css marquee.
http://jsfiddle.net/46PDe/

Comment: the marquee is a really fast-to-code-up html tag for a quick and dirty demo, the css comes later if the POC flies

Comment: I think I'll use the button instead of the div, will work for this demo, I just set the button's gray background color to white and put border:none on it, looks (appearance-wise) exactly like my original code sample but now it responds to mouse clicks.

Comment: It would help if I had some experience with animation, I had no idea it would be that fast, thank you.  I figured I would pick it up later but that's the shortest code sample I've seen tonight when I looked at several other CSS marquees, nice job.